# Threaded data in Yii2

Tags: activerecord, yii2, hierarchical-data

I am looking for a solution through `Active Record` to get the hierarchical data in single query.

What I am doing now is first fetching all the data and then converting array to desired array with a recursive function.

```
$allUsers = User::find()
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
$arr = Yii::$app->TreeComponent->getUserChildren($allUsers, $userId, $userId);
```

and in TreeComponent

```
public function getUserChildren($src_arr, $currentId, $userId, $parentFound = false)
{
    $cats = array();
    foreach ($src_arr as $row) {
        if ($row['id'] == $userId) {
            $row['parent'] = "";
        }
        if ((!$parentFound && $row['id'] == $currentId) || $row['parent'] == $currentId) {
            $rowData = array();
            foreach ($row as $k => $v)
                $rowData[$k] = $v;
            $cats[] = $rowData;
            if ($row['parent'] == $currentId) {
                $cats = array_merge($cats, $this->fetchRecursive($src_arr, $row['id'], true));
            }
        }
    }
    return $cats;
}
```

Its working fine. But recently I go through [CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp)'s [find('threaded')](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-threaded), I think it will save recursive function execution time and less code.

I am curious if there is any function exists in [Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html) too.

Comment: There is no function for that, but you might want to use [nested lists](https://github.com/creocoder/yii2-nested-sets).

Comment: Yii's AR can't populate hierarchical data in a single call.

You can build a tree like array structure using references to avoid recursion. If you're interested in that I can post an example.

Comment: @nineinchnick yes please i would like to see the example.

Comment: A quick googling gives [such example](http://tech.vg.no/2011/10/31/building-tree-structures-in-php-using-references/). This one looks like sorting is important, so I'd add an `isset` check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Yii2 there is no such functionality. CakePHP will also do multiple queries in the background and just wrap it in a multi-threaded call. The main speed-advantage you would gain if you could actually only perform one single query.

There are two ways to achieve this:

- Your way...fetching everything and merge it within your code
- NestedSet pattern as mentioned in a comment above

**NestedSet**

For Yii2 there us a very good extension implementing the nested set pattern. You can find it here:

https://github.com/creocoder/yii2-nested-sets

**Pros and Cons**

The advantage is - obviously - that you can fetch everything with a single query. You can even save multiple trees in one table.

The main disadvantage is sorting according to columns while still maintaining the tree structure. The nested set is organised with two attributes: left and right. This means, that all the data is sorted according to these two attributes. To fetch a tree-structure sorted eg by name, you'll still have to implement a code-side functionality to alter the received data-set after the query. The cleanest way is to sort the data while saving...meaning insert a new record according to its place in your desired sorting

Wikipedia has a very good explenation of the nested set:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

This illustration shows how it works:

[image: NestedSet illustration]

Example: 'slacks' and 'jackets' are children of 'suits' as both their left and right attributes are between the left (3) and right (8) value of 'suits'. If you wanted to add a child to 'jackets' you would inject it between 6 and 7...therefore increasing all values higher or equal than 7 by two. The newly injected child of 'jackets' would then receive a left value of 7 and a right value of 8.

As you can see, you can now easily fetch a whole (sub-)tree simply by filtering the left and right attributes. I f you wanted everything from 'suits' downwards your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE left >= 3 AND right <= 8 ORDER BY left ASC
```

**Final Answer to your question**

*If your main focus is comfort*

No. There is no such functionality. If you still want a regular tree in your db and just don't want to care about merging the data, you would have to write a similliar functionality to CakePHPs methods. This should be quite easy and I think there would be a lot of people interested in it.

*If your main concern is speed*

Use the nested set. It's one hell of a pattern and sooo powerful!

Comment: Thanks for the Answer @PLM57 . My main concern is speed as there is thousands of records. And in my case there can be more than 2 child of a node, if nested set will be still valid approach?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, you can have as many children per node as you want! Its not like a binary tree where only two children are allowed...its a regular tree but organised differently (with left/right-attributes instead of a parent ID). This illustration in the wiki article explains it very well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model#/media/File:NestedSetModel.svg

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to store a tree and fetch it with no recursion. It requires 2 tables.

```
tree_data

  Column   |  Type   |                                         
-----------+---------+
 id        | integer | 
 parent_id | integer |
 level     | integer |
 sort      | integer | 


tree_structure

 Column |  Type   |                          
--------+---------+
 parent | integer |
 child  | integer |
```

Example:

```
select * from tree_data;

 id | parent_id | level | sort 
----+-----------+-------+------
  1 |         0 |     0 | 1000
  2 |         1 |     1 | 1000
  3 |         1 |     1 | 2000
  4 |         1 |     1 | 1500
  5 |         1 |     1 | 1750
  6 |         5 |     2 | 1000


select * from tree_structure order by parent, child;

 parent | child 
--------+-------
      1 |     1
      1 |     2
      1 |     3
      1 |     4
      1 |     5
      1 |     6
      2 |     2
      3 |     3
      4 |     4
      5 |     5
      5 |     6
      6 |     6
```

The resulting tree:

```
├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   ├── 4
│   ├── 5
│       ├── 6
│   ├── 3
```

To query the tree:

```
SELECT tree_data.* 
FROM tree_data
INNER JOIN tree_structure ON tree_data.id = tree_structure.child and tree_structure.parent = 1 
ORDER BY level, sort;
```

Here is a set of classes for [yii2 to manage this ree](https://github.com/10111282/yii2-sortable-tree)